# Converting a local time to EST time zone

Tags: java

I am pulling a time from a table and I want to display it in EST time zone.  Not sure how to do this with tables. I made a time picker and it displays EST times, when I am updating I pull the time from the table which is in local time, and the time picker(which is a combo box) needs to have the local time converted to EST.
modStartTimeCmbo.setValue(appointment.getStartDate().toLocalTime());

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is the return type of `getStartDate()`?

Comment: https://howtodoinjava.com/java/date-time/convert-date-time-to-est-est5edt/ this would be helpful